# MacOS rejects all the available ports when starting a docker

Tags: docker

I'm trying to build a simple docker image to test [this](https://github.com/daattali/beautiful-jekyll) static web template.

Steps:
Refer to the post [here](https://github.com/daattali/beautiful-jekyll#advanced-local-development-using-docker)

My error:

```
user$ docker run -d -p 4000:4000 --name beautiful-jekyll -v "$PWD":/srv/jekyll beautiful-jekyll
6b52867fdfa3af710e2ef6ef80df707ba90dae8114aba4e19177a9da8068d6a2
docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:4000: bind: address already in use.
```

My OS:
Mac Catalina 10.15.2

I have tried

1) Deleting all the docker images and rebuilding it

2) Restarting Docker

3) Try a different port in the command `docker run`'s `-p` parameter.

4) Tried `lsof` to find which process is using those ports. Returns nothing.

None of the above helped.

Comment: replace `-p` with `-P`, docker will assign an available port, then with `docker ps` you'll find the port allocated

Comment: @Jean-JacquesMOIROUX `docker ps` returns nothing under `port`

Comment: make sure on your Dockerfile you `EXPOSE 4000` for the build of your image

Comment: Thanks, I tried `-P` and it worked